# "não + verb" when speaking - pronunciation

Tags: pronúncia

In casual speach I often, if not always, hear that "não + verb" pronounced as "no + verb".
For instance, "não fui" I hear as "[no] fui", which is "no" as it's pronounced in Spanish.

Why? Or is it how it appears to me? Or is how it's supposed to be pronounced, and is used in the normal speach too?

Comment: Could you say where you've heard it? It is possible that you heard the informal pronunciation *num* of *não*.

Comment: @Schilive I didn't hear "num", I hear "[no]". I'm a newbie in Portuguese, also

Comment: Koharim67, so you heard like English *no*, but without the *w* in the end? I asked where because, maybe, some Brazilians from the South do it, or it may be some archaism from some Portugal region, or it may be Spanish influence. The theory for the reason is very dependent on where you heard it.

Comment: The way it's described, this pronunciation doesn't seem usual at all. I also think it's important to know where you're hearing it from to be able to answer the question.

Comment: @Schilive I said "no in Spanish"; I don't think that it has to do with the way they pronounce it, but instead the way I hear it.

Comment: @Koharim67, it could also have been one of those occasion when you say a word completely differently without even noticing.

Comment: Koharim, where do you hear it? Is it from Brazilians, Portuguese, Angolans?

Comment: I'm sorry but não is always nasalized. No Brazilian would say no for não, or any other variety of Portuguese. It is probably that you can't hear it.

Comment: Quite possible! we can year otfen:  "num fui" but also "na fui" (alentejo) and "no[u] fui" norte portugal.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:

The standard pronunciation for the word "não" follows its spelling exactly as would be expected.  In relaxed pronunciation or when we are speaking a little quicker, especially when it's followed by a verb, however, it often becomes "num", just as in "eu num fui" or "eu num sei". Sometimes, "num" may be even shortened to "nu" but I never heard it changed into "no".